# Add nuget package into project file without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nuget

I am looking for solution to add/update new nuget packages to exiting project file .csproj but without Visual Studio. I gone this [post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/installing-nuget-packages-directly-from.html) here it download package it on local machine. But we want same process that Visual Studio do

1. Download dll
2. Add reference in project file
3. update package.config file

Is it possible that I can achieve this outside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using Nuget.exe and the `install-package` etc. Powershell cmdlets. See [the blog post *Installing NuGet Packages outside of Visual Studio*](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) for details!